# Get numbers Yacc & Lex

Tags: c, parsing, yacc, lex

I need to write parsers and lexers for a specific file type and store the information I need. But it doesn't even come out to get a list of digits from the test file

text.txt

```
port (
     3,  5,  7,
     9, 11, 13,
    15, 17, 19
);
```

I use simple rules for lexical analysis

lex.l

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

delim [ \t\n]
ws {delim}+
digit [0-9]
number {digit}+
sym [a-zA-z]

%%
port { return PORT; }
"(" { return OBRACE; }
")" { return CBRACE; }
";" { return SEMICOLON; }
"," { return COMMA; }
{delim} {}
{number} { yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
%%

int yywrap (void)
{
    return 1;
}
```

For parsing I have to use recursion

yacc.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int yylex();
extern char *yytext;
int ports[9];
int curPort = 0;
%}

%union {
    int ival;
    char *cval;
}

%token NUMBER;
%token PORT OBRACE CBRACE COMMA SEMICOLON

%type <ival> exp NUMBER

%%
commands: /* empty */
    | commands command
    ;

command:
    ports_set
    ;

ports_set:
    OBRACE exp CBRACE SEMICOLON
    ;

exp: 
    NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
    | exp COMMA NUMBER { ports[curPort++] = $3; }
    ;
%%

extern FILE *yyin;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    yyin = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    do {
        yyparse();
    } while (!feof(yyin));
    
    fclose(yyin);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        printf("port %d: %d\n", i, ports[i]);   
    }
}

int yyerror(char const *s)
{
    printf("ERROR: %s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

As a result, I get an error and a ports array with zero values

```
$ ./test.exe
ERROR: syntax error
port 0: 0
port 1: 0
port 2: 0
port 3: 0
port 4: 0
port 5: 0
port 6: 0
port 7: 0
port 8: 0
```

Comment: The token `PORT` does not appear anywhere in your grammar. But it's the first token which will be returned by your lexer. So the syntax error seems predictable.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me)

Comment: @sepp2k Could you then tell me how to describe grammar. Because I've been trying to figure out how to use yacc and lex for week now, but no results.
Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @sepp2k: the lex file has `"(" { return OBRACE; }`. I found that confusing, too, and it's high on my list of why I think quoted character tokens are much more readable.

Comment: @Killlin: aside from the meaningless and/or misleading names and the missing `PORT` token, the grammar is OK. The part written in C could use some work: global variables and fixed-size arrays without overflow checks are two signs of poor design. If you had used a name like `number_list` instead of `exp` for the list of numbers, it might have seemed more obvious that the semantic value should not be a single number but rather a list of numbers (presumably dynamically allocated).